# How to generate report from mysql database in android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, report

I was thinking about creating an app which could be used to add data into a MySQL database and generate the data into a downloadable report, but I'm wondering: is it possible to generate and download a report (PDF or Excel file) using an android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting directly to your MySQL database from your android app is not a good idea

You may want to create a web page (php etc) on the server that does the query and returns JSON back to your android app

The result will be cleaner and you can control access

You could even require security tokens to be passed form the app to your page and validate before returning the data